# Reusing Controller Action based on ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I will have a registration form on my website which will firstly show the boardrules / legal. Once accepted it will then show the main registration form. Using a ViewModel as below:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int Readrules { get; set; }
    public int Coppa { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Register(MyViewModel model)
{
    ... at this stage model.Readrules and model.Coppa will contain the values passed
        as query string parameters tat you could use here
}
```

The idea is if I go to `/register` it will show the rules and then `/register?readrules=1` it will then show the registration form. This is how it was done in PHP but now I am migrating to ASP.NET..

What is the best way of doing this? Can I redirect to the same action and just parse the value of model.ReadRules or must I use more than one action? I would prefer to keep this in one action and just check if `model.ReadRules == 1` and either display the boardrules or registration form.

Thanks

Comment: Why not show rules in /register and handle registration in /register/form ? Would be much simpler. What's the reason behind the query string?

Comment: the query string is from my PHP code which I am migrating, also if I have a query string the ViewModel elements are automatically populated and I thought I could re-use the same Action method for the Registration and Form and then have a separate one to handle the processing. Main reason for the topic was to understand what best practice for this is in ASP.NET MVC as in PHP a lot of data is passed in the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of re-using the *Register* action, you could have different controller actions for displaying the rules, registering and processing the registration, like so:

**Controller Actions:**

```
public ActionResult BoardRules() 
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Register(MyViewModel model)
{
    if (model.ReadRules != 1)
        return RedirectToAction("BoardRules");

    return View();
}

public ActionResult Registration(MyViewModel model)
{
    if (model.ReadRules != 1)
        return RedirectToAction("BoardRules");

    //Process the registration

    return View();
}
```

**Views:**

*BoardRules.cshtml:*

```
@* HTML Displaying Rules *@
<a href="@Url.Action("Register", new { ReadRules = 1 })">Accept Rules</a>
```

*Register.cshtml:*

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Registration", "[Controller Name]", new { ReadRules = 1 }))
{
    @* Form Fields *@
    <input type="submit" value="Process Registration" />
}
```

*Registration.cshtml*

```
<h2>Congratz on Registering!</h2>
```

Comment: when a user accepts the boardrules how am i able to come back to this same Action and provide the registration view?

Comment: I updated my previous answer with a more thorough response of handling action navigation between the different actions of your controller rather than trying to re-purpose a single action.

Comment: i prefer this answer. If instead of going from `/register` to `/registration` I want it to go to `/register/form` how would I go about doing that?

Comment: My answer is based on performing actions from a single controller. So `Register`, `Registration` and `BoardRules` are all actions from that controller. What you're asking about would break that convention and require routing rules. I would recommend re-evaluating the need for "form".

Comment: i will create another topic for this as its a general question

Comment: Ok, I hope that this was at least helpful in outlining action navigation and redirection.

Answer (score 1):

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
    return View("boardrules");       //Default
}

public ActionResult Register(MyViewModel model)
{
    if (model.ReadRules == 1)
    {
        model.ReadRules++;            //Next time it won't be 1 but step 2
        return View("registration",model);
    }
    else
    {
      //Do IF or Case for other step
    }
    return View("boardrules");       //Default
}
```

Comment: would I need another action as well for when they submit registration? I was looking for something which was encapsulated in one view for display with a toggle between registration and boardrules views and another to process the results (if possible)

Comment: You need one by method type. If your FORM is POST than add [HttpPost] over the action. You can have 2 actions that use the same view as in the example I provided.